# Does defining a vector before a single bit input affect the single bit?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to define a module, but SystemVerilog thinks that my "works" is 3 bits. Does having that logic right after a 3-bit vector of "In" affect it? I am trying to connect to a test bench that instantiates this module but keep getting a port width mismatch. I put the error messages below (The message is from when I tried to do .In(In) etc.).

Module header:

```
module random
    (input logic [2:0] In, works,
    output logic [7:0] Out);
```

Test header:

```
module random_test;
    logic [2:0] In;
    logic works;
    logic [7:0] Out;

    random r(.In, .works, .Out);
```

Error:

```
Warning-[PCWM-W] Port connection width mismatch
tests.sv, 8
"random r( .In (In),  .works (works),  .Out (Out));"
The following 1-bit expression is connected to 3-bit port "works" of module 
"random", instance "r".
Expression: works
Instantiated module defined at: "random.sv", 4
Use +lint=PCWM for more details.


Warning-[PCWM-W] Port connection width mismatch
tests.sv, 8
"random r( .In (In),  .works (works),  .Out (Out));"
The following 8-bit expression is connected to 1-bit port "Out" of module 
"random", instance "r".
Expression: Out
Instantiated module defined at: "random.sv", 4
Use +lint=PCWM for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

`works` is 3 bits because it inherits the `[2:0]` from the `input` declaration.

To get `works` to be a single bit, declare it using the `input` keyword:

```
module random
    (
    input logic [2:0] In,
    input logic works,
    output logic [7:0] Out
    );
endmodule
```

It does not give me a warning on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/G3Pk).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I changed the header, but it still gives the same error

Comment: I just edited the names of some files in order to maintain anonymity. Let me fix that

Comment: I have a file with multiple modules and another file with multiple test benches for each file. I run a command "vlogan -sverilog -nc random_tests.sv" then "vcs -sverilog -nc random_test" to run the specific test bench for the random module. Maybe that could make an impact?

Comment: Yep. I agree your code works and looking at it with my systemVerilog knowledge I know it should. I am just confused on how in my situation it wouldn't work and if there were some extraneous factors that might play a role

Comment: Are the commands I listed such as "vlogan -sverilog -nc random_tests.sv" custom verilog commands or part of regular systemverilog? If so, the minimum reproducible example is putting the test bench and the module into two separate files then running the commands I wrote in a comment before. My original question hinged on my belief that these commands wouldn't affect the ports at all, but since that might be the issue now I wanted to make sure. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you have a list of declarations separated by commas `,`. Verilog has a set of implicit defaults that carry over from one declaration to the next. At a minimum, you need to explicitly add a datatype to `works` to reset the implicit data type back to a single bit.

```
module random
    (input logic [2:0] In, logic works,
    output logic [7:0] Out);
```

See section *23.2.2.3 Rules for determining port kind, data type, and direction* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)